# What is the difference between "at" and "positioned" in "/execute"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The `/execute` command is a versatile command used to execute commands on behalf of other entities, or to test for conditionals before executing a command. It offers multiple different parameters to set who, what, when, and where to execute the command.

There are two parameters that look very similar: `at` and `positioned as`.
The Minecraft Wiki has a clear description of what each one does: `at` is used to position at an entity, while `positioned` can be used to specify coordinates.

But however, there is another way to specify an entity: using `positioned as ??`. This also offers us to specify an entity instead of coordinates to execute the command at.

What is the difference between these two parameters, and in which situations should I prefer each of them?

Comment: I think that `positioned as` includes orientation, i.e. where the target is looking.

Comment: No, you cannot set "when" to execute something. Only `/schedule` can do that directly and you can use ticking things or other things that have timings to make timers indirectly, based on conditions.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that `/execute positioned as` exists. I've never used it before, in my 192 Minecraft commands answers that use/mention `/execute` or elsewhere. It's even confusingly named, because it's **not** like `/execute as` at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question. `at` changes the position of execution using the position, rotation, and dimension of the target. `positioned as` only uses the position of the target.

You can test this yourself by running this command from a command block in the overworld (make sure the chunk is loaded):

```
/execute if entity @e[tag=test] positioned as @p run setblock ~ ~2 ~ glass
```

The entity with the tag is just a switch so you can activate the command from the end/nether. The command will place a glass block at your position but in the overworld (which proves that `positioned as` only uses the position). Now try using `at` and you will see that the glass block is placed not only at your position, but also in the same dimension you are in.